# KnockoutJS Validation - nested ViewModel as validatedobservable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a KnockoutJS viewmodel that acts as a "master" viewmodel for several modular viewmodels. These modular vm's utilize knockout validated properties for their own form validations. I would like to make these viewmodels `validatedObservable` in the master viewmodel, so I can simply check each if `isValid` is true:

```
function MasterViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.addUserViewModel = ko.validatedObservable(new AddUserViewModel());
}

function AddUserViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.username = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

    self.addUser = = function () {
        if(self.isValid()) {
            // Perform add user logic here
        }
    }.bind(self);
}
```

However, the `isValid` method does not exist for the child viewmodel when I attempt to call it. Is there an issue with adding a `validatedObservable` property that is a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isValid` is added by the function `validatedObservable` and will therefore only be available inside the `MasterViewModel`.

You could use `ko.validation.group` when you want to check if the model is valid inside the model itself:

```
function AddUserViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.username = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

    var errors = ko.validation.group(self, { deep: true });
    self.addUser = = function () {
        if (!errors().length) {
            // Perform add user logic here
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This answer satisfies my requirements completely, thanks @sroes. It should be noted, just for anybody else trying this, that the `errors` variable needs to be declared _after_ all of the extended observables of the viewmodel have been declared.